# How can I select a random name from a list and store it in a variable?

Tags: perl, file-io

I'm already developing that project to my family, but now i'm needing to link a Name to another aleatory(remember that the first name i have it) and store only the second name in a variable, remember that this list is a file(*.txt) with some names, but how i can do this? Thanks.

Comment: What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: It's to aleatory select a name that is stored in a file.

Comment: aleatory = randomly here I believe?

Comment: Yes, it's because i'm from Brazil and here we speak: Aleatório, that is the same of ramdom. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry Nathan, read a few times, still don't get it - can you expand a bit?  Is the link you mention significant?  Or are you just after randomly getting a name from a list of names in a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, you seem to want to get a random name from a file. Assuming these names are on separate lines, here's what you can do (please read about the built-in `rand`, `int` and `chomp` methods in [perldoc perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) to see how they work):

```
my @names = <>;
chomp(@names);
my $random_name = $names[int(rand(@names))];
```

Breaking this down into steps, this is what it does:

- first, we read in the file. If you pipe the file into your script (like `perl myscript.pl < names.txt`), you can read directly from STDIN, with `<>`.
- then, we remove all the newlines from each line with `chomp`.
- now we want to get a random element from the list:
- `@list` in scalar context get the number of elements in the list (for example, 4)
- `rand(4)`: get a random number between 0 and 4 (so we could have a number between 0 and 3.999999...)
- `int(some number from above)` that was a floating-point number, so let's round it down (so now we have either 0, 1, 2, or 3: which is exactly the possible array indexes for our list!
- use that as the array index into @list and we're done!

Comment: It's even easier in Perl6 `my $value = @list.pick`

Comment: And even overly complex for Perl5: `$names[rand @names]` will do just fine.

Comment: yeah I totally didn't intuit that an integer would be coerced from a floating point value for an array index, but after all, Perl DWIM :)

Comment: @Ether: welcome to "integer context" :)   (Array or list-slice indicies, operands of .. where the other operand is numeric, substr 2nd and 3rd operands, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The English in your question is so bad that I'm having a really hard time understanding what you are asking.

But what about this?

```
use List::Util qw(shuffle);
my @array = shuffle(<>);
print shift @array;
```

That reads from STDIN, you can always use open to open a file then use  on your file handle.

Here it is with file IO:

```
use List::Util qw(shuffle);
open my $fh, "<", "out.txt";
my @array = shuffle(<$fh>);
print shift @array;
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try this and very sorry about my english :(

Comment: @Nathan thanks for my "word of the day": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleatoricism

Comment: When i try to do this i'm  getting this error: `"suffle" is not exported by the List::Util module`

Comment: Looks like a typo?  Should be "shuffle".

Comment: This is pretty wasteful of compute time and the random number generator's entropy.  If you want a random stream, shuffle the list.  If you just want one random element of the array, just ask for that.